# Difference between pry and pry-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pry

What is the difference (implementation wise) in pry gem and pry-rails gem?

Comment: usually the -rails gems provide extra things for integration with rails, so if from rails, you typically use these.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Comparing their implementation doesn't make sense, because they're two different things: an IRb alternative and a plugin to make the former the Rails console.

The pry-rails gem simply [adds an initializer](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails/blob/master/lib/pry-rails/railtie.rb) to change the Rails console to Pry and [adds some Pry commands](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails/blob/master/lib/pry-rails/commands.rb) specific to Rails. Pry-rails depends on Pry, and there's no reason you couldn't use Pry with Rails without pry-rails, it just makes it easier.

Comment: How do I use pry-rails to debug Rails applications?

Comment: means , can pry do whatever pry-rails can do ?

Comment: @huzefabiyawarwala Yes.

Comment: @AlanCoromano place `binding.pry` anywhere in your Rails code to add a breakpoint e.g. in a controller action. Go to that path in the browser and you'll see the breakpoint in the terminal where `rails server` is running. Here's a screencast to learn more about it http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails